# Read or write the thumbnail embedded in a JPEG image in Qt or Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt. I want to know how to read or write the **thumbnail embedded** in **JPEG image** using **QT classes**.

I found that the “**QMediaMetaData Namespace**” contains the “**ThumbnailImage**” identifier containing the thumbnail data. But I didn’t get any examples related to that.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: [This](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Get_thumbnail_embedded_in_a_JPG_image_using_Qt) link is the first result when I search "qt jpeg thumbnail" on duckduckgo.